# MacOS C++ CFRunLoopRun() is not blocking a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, core-foundation

I have this program, which is trying to use MacOS `CoreFoundation` API `CFRunLoopRun()` to block a thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

CFRunLoopRef loop = nullptr;

int main() {
    std::thread t1([](){char n; std::cin>>n; CFRunLoopStop(loop);});
    std::thread t2([](){loop=CFRunLoopGetCurrent(); CFRunLoopRun();});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;

}
```

I am trying to understand why `CFRunLoopRun()` in thread t2 is not blocking, whereas when if I remove thread t2, and execute same command in main thread then that blocks. what is the right way to call `CFRunLoopRun()` in t2 thread?

Comment: How do you know it's not "blocking"? What is happening when you run your program? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: I mean I can see that in debugger it is not blocking. Program is just exiting as soon as it executes.

Comment: Check the returned value of CFRunLoopGetCurrent(). It's nullptr. You don't create the thread with Core Foundation, thus the thread does not have a message loop.

Comment: @S.M. Can you explain what is CoreFoundation thread?

Comment: NSThread initializes a message pump and a run loop.

Comment: Also a run loop requires an input source. Read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW25)